# Non-Indian Hindus

Tags: philosophy, culture, sects

Are there European/American Hindus who converted to Hinduism, but not the newly reformed sects like Hare Krishna, Arya Samaj, Brahmo Samaj, but who adopted traditional sects like Shaivism, Vaishnavism, Suryaism, etc.?

Comment: Yes. See http://www.hinduismtoday.com/